# Pre define vars before loading namespace

Tags: clojure

I have a namespace called some.core with the following,

```
(ns some.core)
(defonce name-of-something :a)
```

then from a leiningen plugin I would like to predefine name-of-something before loading the namespace so that when the namespace is loaded it is already defined defonce won't define it.

```
    (eval-in-project project
                     `(do (create-ns 'some.core)
                          (intern 'some.core 'name-of-something :b)))
```

but with the above I keep getting,

```
Can't intern namespace-qualified symbol
```

error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Updated to take into account the comments below. I leave the original answer under the horizontal rule so as not to remove the context of the comments.)*

TL;DR fix:

```
`(do ... (intern 'some.core '~'name-of-something :b))
                          ; ^- note the '~'
```

The problem is that the `(do ...)` form is syntax-quoted (quoted with a backtick, as opposed to a single quote), so symbols inside it get replaced with namespace-qualified variants (after being resolved to determine which namespace they should be qualified with). This excludes symbols which are already namespace-qualified as well as those which contain a dot.

The problematic symbol in the above is `name-of-something` -- dot-free and unqualified. To rectify the situation, you can replace `'name-of-something` with `'~'name-of-something`; the first quote is included in the output of syntax-quote, the tilde causes the value of the form immediately following it to be included in the expansion of the syntax-quoted region and finally `'name-of-something` is the form itself, evaluating to the (unqualified) symbol `name-of-something`:

If unquoting was unnecessary, replacing the backtick with a single quote would also solve the problem. (The final solution -- mentioned for completeness -- would be to build the form manually: `(list 'do ...)`.)

---

*(Original answer follows.)*

You need to change the backtick to single quote:

```
`(do (create-ns 'some.core) ...)
; change to
'(do (create-ns 'some.core) ...)
^- note the quote
```

What happens with the backtick, or "syntax quote", is that `'name-of-something` gets munged to `'current-namespace/name-of-something`, causing `intern` to complain. (Note that `some.core` stays untouched -- due to magic treatment of dots in symbols, I believe. The other symbols -- `do`, `create-ns` and `intern` -- are also replaced with namespace-qualified variants, but that doesn't cause any problems.)

Comment: but then I can not pass vars from the context, :b is actually read from the command line

Comment: In this case, you can replace `'name-of-something` with `~'name-of-something`. Note the tilde for "unquote".

Comment: with the tilde in place it is trying to evaluate name-of-something, I get unable to resolve symbol

Comment: Hm, actually that would be `'~'name-of-something` if the form you want looks like `(intern 'some.core 'name-of-something :b)` without quotes. The way this works is: (1) first quote gets included in the form output by syntax-quote; (2) tilde unquotes the immediately following form and has its value inserted in the current spot in the syntax-quoted form; (3) `'name-of-something` is the form you want whose value is the symbol `name-of-something`.

Comment: Right, I missed one quote in the first comment. The version from my second comment should work, though.

Comment: Great. Edited the answer to include this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just load the namespace with the defonce first and then change it with alter-var-root.

Both are pretty crazy workarounds, but what you're asking is pretty crazy to begin with.